# x86-64 ELF initial stack layout when calling glibc

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, nasm, glibc

Basically, I read through parts of http://www.nasm.us/links/unix64abi and at page 29, it shows the initial process stack of a C program.

My question is: I'm trying to interface with glibc from x86-64 nasm and based on what the above shows, argc should be at rsp. So the following code should print argc:

```
[SECTION .data]
PrintStr: db "You just entered %d arguments.", 10, 0

[SECTION .bss]

[SECTION .text]
extern printf
global main

main:
     mov rax, 0        ; Required for functions taking in variable no. of args
     mov rdi, PrintStr
     mov rsi, [rsp]
     call printf
     ret
```

But it doesn't. Can someone enlighten me if I have made any mistakes in my code or tell me what the actual stack structure is?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**: I just randomly tried some offsets and changing the "mov rsi, [rsp]" to "mov rsi, [rsp+28]" did the trick.

But this means that the stack structure shown is wrong. Does anyone know what the initial stack layout is for an x86-64 elf? An equivalent of http://asm.sourceforge.net/articles/startup.html would be really nice.

**UPDATE 2:**
I left out how I build this code. I do it by:

```
nasm -f elf64 -g <filename>
gcc <filename>.o -o <outputfile>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial stack layout contains `argc` at the stack pointer, followed by the *array* `char *argv[]`, not a pointer to it like `main` receives. Therefore, to call main, you need to do something like:

```
pop %rdi
mov %rsp,%rsi
call main
```

In reality there is usually a wrapper function that calls `main`, rather than the startup code doing it directly.

If you want to simply print `argv[0]`, you could do something like:

```
pop %rdi
pop %rdi
call puts
xor %edi,%edi
jmp exit
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Just to clarify, I'm not calling a C program with a main function, but just using C library functions. I updated how the code is built in the question. I tried having another global label call the main label, but then it failed at the link stage (gcc is used to link the code). Apparently main must be a global label in this case.

Comment: If you're going to use libc functions, you should be aware that bypassing the libc startup code may cause them to crash. For example glibc probably wants to initialize the `%gs` thread-local storage selector even if threads aren't being used, to make `sysenter`-type syscalls with it and to store other random junk there. You should either create a global `main` in asm and let the libc startup code call it, or omit libc entirely and perform all your syscalls in asm.

Comment: Hi, am I bypassing libc startup code here? I was following how Jeff Duntemann's "Assembly Language Step by Step" called C code from nasm. Could you provide me with examples of how not to bypass libc startup code if I'm doing so? Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I'm a fool. Somehow I thought you had written a `_start` entry point since that's how most people do asm-only programs. If you used `main`, then the stack will contain nothing meaningful and the arguments will be `argc` in `rdi` and `argv` (of type `char **`) in `rsi`.

Comment: Ok I kind of just realized why argc is in `rdi` and argv in `rsi` as that is how arguments are passed in x86-64. Just didn't know that it even applies to the `main` label. Thanks for the help! Btw do you know of an equivalent to [http://asm.sourceforge.net/articles/startup.html](http://asm.sourceforge.net/articles/startup.html) for x86-64? Because the stack layout there is correct for i386 whereas the one in [http://www.nasm.us/links/unix64abi](http://www.nasm.us/links/unix64abi) doesn't tally. Or is it because I used `main` and it applies for `_start`?

Comment: Yes it's because you used `main`.

Comment: Also note that `_start` and `main` are not at all the same on i386 either. `_start` gets `argc` followed by the *array* of string pointers on the stack, whereas `main` gets `argc` followed by `argv` (a pointer to the array of string pointers), also followed by a (usually unused and nonstandard) pointer to the array of environment variable string pointers.

Comment: Hi R.., I really appreciate the help you've given me. I think I understand it much more clearly now. Thanks.