# Can this Linux / 32bit x86 assembly "Hello, World" be made smaller still?

Tags: assembly, code-golf

The following 32bit x86 Linux program prints a string of arbitrary length (as long as a program can be, anyway) and does `exit(0)` afterwards:

```
.global _start             ; notice on entry here, all regs but %esp are zero
_start:
    call  .L0              ; offset == strlen, provided by your assembler
.byte 'H','e','l','l','o',',',' ','W','o','r','l','d'
.L0:
    pop   %ecx             ; ret addr is starting addr of string
    mov   -4(%ecx),%edx    ; argument to `call`, 4 bytes: strlen
    inc   %ebx             ; stdout == 1
    movb  $4, %al          ; SYS_write == 4
    int   $0x80
    xchg  %eax,%ebp        ; %ebp is still zero
    xchg  %eax,%ebx        ; SYS_exit == 1, return value == 0
    int   $0x80
```

If one's willing to sacrifice the position-independence (instead, force the linker to insert the string address), and not care about the program returning zero, one can get it down to:

```
.global _start
_start:
    movb  $4, %al
    inc   %ebx
    mov   $.L0, %ecx       ; this address is calculated when linking
    movb  $.Lend-.L0, %dl  ; strlen, calculated by assembler
    int   $0x80
    xchg  %eax,%ebx
    int   %0x80
.L0:
.byte 'H','e','l','l','o',',',' ','W','o','r','l','d'
.Lend:
```

Both of these can be assembled/linked via `as --32 -o x.o x.S; ld -s -m elf_i386 x.o`, and run just fine. The second one is 26 Bytes of code. If you permit a crash after printing `Hello, World` then leave the last two instructions out, 23 Bytes. That's as low as I could go.

Question that's always bugged me, is it possible to squeeze a few more bytes off this ? Pure speculation of mine gives these possible leads:

- Somehow use parts of the 'Hello, World' itself as code ?
- Anyone knows a usable syscall easter egg ?
- trick the linker into making the entrypoint a 16-bit address so that `movw $.L0, %cx` could be used (saves one byte) ?
- Do an 8-bit offset `jmp` to a place that's known (or created via assembler / linker invocation magic) to contain the necessary instructions for the `exit(...)` syscall, saving one byte over the `xchg; int` sequence ?

Or else, can it be *proven* that this actually *is* the smallest well-behaved (no crash / return code zero) Linux/x86 "Hello, World" ?

### Edit

To clarify, the question is *not* about minimizing the size of the ELF executable; techniques for that are long-known. I'm explicitly inquiring about the size of a Linux 32bit x86 assembly program that performs the equivalent of what the compiled code for:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    puts("Hello, World");
    exit(0); /* or whatever code */
}
```

would do.
In fact, I'll be happy about anything that does not require *manual* editing of the ELF headers. If you find a way to e.g. stuff the `"Hello, World"` into some ELF object and referencing that from the assembly source, using only the assembler / linker command line and/or a mapfile input, I'd consider it valid enough, even though that *increases* the size of the ELF executable. I just want to know if the instruction sequence to print "Hello, World" and `exit()` afterwards can be shrunk still.
The question is about *code size*, not *executable size*.

Comment: Where are you trying to break in? ;-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/284797/hello-world-in-less-than-20-bytes

Comment: @Luigi Plinge: Beaten me on time ;)

Comment: Will you please ask this question on our new [Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) ?

Comment: @Luigi: The "hello world in <20 bytes" isn't limited to Linux/x86 assembly. I've read the posting, the smallest Linux/i386 program in there is > 30 Bytes.

Comment: @rlb.usa: haven't used the SO child sites yet; I admit I like good old SO ;-)

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Assembly is a safe language - hard to hack ;-)

Comment: @FrankH: I thought especially your idea to "use part of the string as code" was very sneaky. +1 for sure, and good luck!

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Thx. Another idea that just came to mind is to use a sequence: `movl ...,%esp; popad; int 0x80; pop %eax; int 0x80` with the stackpointer and contents taken from a suitably-prepared address within the executable; syscall numbers/args would come from there. Can that thing be done with assembler/linker command line ?

Comment: This also can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842001/x86-64-elf-initial-stack-layout-when-calling-glibc (the 32bit variant of course)

Comment: BTW, did you try the `.ascii` directive for embedding strings? If you want a terminating null byte, try `.asciiz`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's code golf.

Answer (score 2):

It's been done back in 1999. Have a look at [this page](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html) (spoiler: the end result is a 45-byte ELF file). Make sure to read [the postscript](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensyps.html) too.

Comment: I've _not_ been talking about the minimum size achievable for an ELF file that "does `exit(42)`"- this is specifically about the instruction sequence to actually _print_ "Hello, World".

Comment: From the same place, Hello world in 62 bytes http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/hello.asm.txt

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward translation of the C code, using libc, results in 16 bytes of instructions:

```
.S:
    .asciz "Hello, World"
.globl main
main:
    push $.S
    call puts
    add $4, %esp
    xor %eax, %eax
    ret
```

If you use x86-64 instead if x86-32, the calling convention passes arguments in registers so we can skip the stack manipulation, and

```
main:
    mov $.S, %rdi
    call puts
    xor %eax, %eax
    ret
```

is only 15 bytes of code.

Comment: In your 32-bit code when you used _RET_ did you remember to adjust the stack to account for the bytes you pushed before `puts`?

Comment: The problem with this is that you're not counting all the C runtime library code you're linking in.